# JQuery Autocomplete not working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter-3

This is the **jquery** at the head:

```
$(function(){
    var $sfield = $('#term').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response){
            var url = "<?php echo site_url('admin/get_email'); ?>";
              $.get(url, {term:request.term}, function(term){
                response($.map(term, function(countries) {
                    return {
                        value: aauth_users.email
                    };
                }));
              }, "json");  
        },
        minLength: 2,
        autofocus: true
    });
});
```

This is my **view:**

```
<form action="admin/get_email" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="remail">Recipient Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="term" name="term" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
</form
```

This is my **Controller:**

```
public function get_email()
    {
        $this->load->model('suggest_email');
        $term = $_GET['term'];
        $countries = $this->suggest_email->get_email($term);
        echo json_encode($countries);
    }
```

and this is my **model:**

```
class Suggest_email extends CI_Model
{
  function get_email($term)
  {
    $this->db->like('email', $term, 'after');
    $query = $this->db->get('aauth_users');
    return $query->result();
  }
}
```

In chrome console, I can clearly see an error:

> http://[::1]/sent/theme/js/jquery.min.js:4 [GET]
>   http://[::1]/sent/index.php/admin/get_email?term=vivo@att.com 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

Comment: in jquery your expecting json response from server .. but from server object is retrieving try to return json data from php page

Answer (score 0):

The program can't locate your js files for jquery and jquery ui.
Please add them at the bottom of the page after the closing body tag. You'll need access to internet for the following cdn links to work.

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.slim.min.js"   integrity="sha256-cRpWjoSOw5KcyIOaZNo4i6fZ9tKPhYYb6i5T9RSVJG8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```